# Difference between using a gerund and using a noun form

Tags: usage

How is using a gerund different from using a noun form? Are they interchangeable? For example, how are the below two sentences different?

You should verify that there is no problem in the code's implementation in the system.

You should verify that there is no problem in implementing the code in the system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the gerund and the noun form have different meanings. What the precise difference is varies by verb, but roughly, the gerund is the *act*, while other noun-forms are the *product*. In this case, "the code's implementation" is the resulting code, whereas "implementing the code" is what the programmer does. The first sentence is about verifying that the code is correct, whereas the second may very well mean "you should verify that the programmer has all necessary tools and information to be able to implement the code".

Answer (score 0):

The *gerund* often means "the action of" and won't always mean the same as the noun. They *can* mean the same thing, but not always so.

In your case:

> the code's implementation

The one doing the action "implement" isn't a person. Rather, "implementation of the code in the system" just means something like "the fact that the code is implemented" or the product of the implementation, which is the system or a part of it.

> implementing the code

The subject doing the action "implement" here would mean a programmer or a team of programmers. It's pointing to the person doing it.

Another example where `noun` =/= `gerund`:

> Growing flowers is fun. 
> The flower's growth is slow.

Additionally, words don't always have both a noun and a verb. Sometimes, you don't have a noun, so you need to use the gerund, and vice versa.